# r- caret package error- createDataParition no observation

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm getting the following error when I try to run `createDataPartition` in caret.

```
Error in createDataPartition(data1, p = 0.8, list = FALSE) : 
  y must have at least 2 data points
```

I ran the same exact same code last night with no errors. Any thoughts?

```
predictors<- with(df, data.frame(xvar, xvar, xvar, xvar))
data1<-with(dfu2, data.frame(data1))
library(caret)
set.seed(1)
trainingRows<- createDataPartition(data1,
                                   p=.80,
                                   list=FALSE)
> dput(head(data1, 15)) structure(list(data1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = "data1", row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data frame `data1` is clearly visible in my environment and has the expected observations. Any thought?

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4):

This does not work because `data1` is a data.frame in your case whereas it should be a vector as it is mentioned the documentation of `?createDataPartition`. See this example:

```
#using your data
data1 <- structure(list(data1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = "data1", row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now if I do:

```
> createDataPartition(data1)
Error in createDataPartition(data1) : y must have at least 2 data points
```

I get the same error as you. Whereas, if it is a vector:

```
> createDataPartition(data1[[1]] )
$Resample1
[1]  1  2  3  4  8  9 12 15
```

It works great.

So just use `data1[[1]]` in your code in the `CreateDataPartition` call and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by changing the target data type from character to factor because the downsample function require the response should be factor type. Hope this will be helpful